# How to stop click event on resize & load if screen width is greater than?

Tags: javascript

I am facing this problem over and over again and just don't know how to solve this. I have a click event that I would like to fire only if the screen width is less than **576px* and if a page is loaded to make this event fire.

But when I resize the browser larger than **576px** the click event still works.

Can someone please help me out how can I solve this common issue that I am facing?

Thanks in advance.

My code:

```
const onSearchMobile = () => {
    let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let searchIcon = document.querySelector('.main-header__search--icon');
    if (screenWidth <= 576) {
        console.log('Yes lower then 576');
        searchIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('clicked!');
        });
    }
};

window.addEventListener('resize', onSearchMobile, false);
window.addEventListener('load', onSearchMobile);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the `width` inside event

```
const onSearchMobile = () => {
  let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
  let searchIcon = document.querySelector('.main-header__search--icon');
  searchIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (screenWidth <= 576) {
      console.log('clicked!');
    }
  });
};

window.addEventListener('resize', onSearchMobile, false);
window.addEventListener('load', onSearchMobile);
```

Using [`MediaQueryList.onchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/onchange)

```
let searchIcon = document.querySelector('.main-header__search--icon')
let clickListener = () => console.log('clicked!')
let mql = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 576px)')

mql.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (e.matches) {
    searchIcon.addEventListener('click', clickListener)
  } else {
    searchIcon.removeEventListener('click', clickListener)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove eventListener:

```
    const onSearchMobile = () => {
    let screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
    let searchIcon = document.querySelector('.main-header__search--icon');
    if (screenWidth <= 576) {
        console.log('Yes lower then 576');
        searchIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log('clicked!');
        });
    }
    else {
        searchIcon.removeEventListener('click');
    }
};

window.addEventListener('resize', onSearchMobile, false);
window.addEventListener('load', onSearchMobile);
```